# How to add custom equality to NUnit while also keeping the default equality check

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, nunit-3.0

Is there a way to make a custom constraint such that NUnit's default equality test is done first, then the custom equality test?

For example, suppose I want to test that `System.Double` values are equal, but treat `Double.PositiveInfinity` as equal to `Double.NegativeInfinity`. I can write a simple test `Comparison` in the code below that checks this special case, then just uses `==`.

- If I use `Is.EqualTo(expected).Using<double>((x, y) => Comparison(x, y));`
  then `NaNisEqualToNaN` fails because I don't have NUnit's default equality test.
- If I use `Is.EqualTo(expected).Or.EqualTo(expected).Using<double>((x, y) => Comparison(x, y));` to combine the custom test and the default test
  then a failing test like `ShouldFail_NegativeInfinityIsKindaEqualTo7` gives a repetitive error message `Expected: 7.0d or 7.0d But was...`

Full code sample:

```cs
using System;
using NUnit.Framework;
using NUnit.Framework.Constraints;

namespace UnitTest
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class Class1
    {
        private Constraint IsKindaEqualTo(double expected)
        {
            // With this line, ShouldFail_NegativeInfinityIsKindaEqualTo7 reports "Expected: 7.0d or 7.0d But was:  ∞"
            return Is.EqualTo(expected).Or.EqualTo(expected).Using<double>((x, y) => Comparison(x, y));

            // With this line, the NaNisEqualToNaN test fails
            //return Is.EqualTo(expected).Using<double>((x, y) => Comparison(x, y));
        }

        private static bool Comparison(double x, double y)
        {
            if (Double.IsInfinity(x) && Double.IsInfinity(y))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return x == y;
            }
        }

        [Test]
        public void NegativeInfinityIsKindaEqualToPositiveInfinity()
        {
            var actual = Double.NegativeInfinity;
            var expected = Double.PositiveInfinity;

            Assert.That(actual, IsKindaEqualTo(expected));
        }

        [Test]
        public void ShouldFail_NegativeInfinityIsKindaEqualTo7()
        {
            var actual = Double.PositiveInfinity;
            var expected = 7.0;

            Assert.That(actual, IsKindaEqualTo(expected));
        }

        [Test]
        public void NaNisEqualToNaN()
        {
            var actual = Double.NaN;
            var expected = Double.NaN;

            Assert.That(actual, Is.EqualTo(expected));
        }

        [Test]
        public void NaNisKindaEqualToNan()
        {
            var actual = Double.NaN;
            var expected = Double.NaN;

            Assert.That(actual, IsKindaEqualTo(expected));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NUnit's equality comparison comes from a class named `NUnitEqualityComparer`. I would create and use one of those inside your `Comparison` method, and wrap everything up in a single comparer. e.g:

```
    private static bool Comparison(double x, double y)
    {
        var nunitComparer = new NUnitEqualityComparer();
        if (nunitComparer.AreEqual(x,y)) return true;

        if (Double.IsInfinity(x) && Double.IsInfinity(y))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return x == y;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Additional thoughts - I'd also be tempted to convert your `IsKindaEqualTo` method into a [Custom Constraint](http://hermit.no/how-to-extend-the-nunit-constraints/). That's a step beyond what you were asking, however. =)

Comment: Thanks! Also the equality test is for a library wrapping NUnit, so conforming to the usual NUnit API isn't really required.